# Upgrading an angular 13 app with js-cookie stops running jest unit tests successfully

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, js-cookie, jest-preset-angular

I have an angular app with version 13 which is using the external dependency **js-cookie** to set and get some cookies in the browser.
As a test environment I am using **jest** with **jest-preset-angular**. See all dependencies of the package.json below.

My problem is that in angular 12 the unit tests of the component which is using `Cookies.set('test', '123')` is running perfectly fine. But with angular 13 while the functionality works and the build (ng build) is running, there is an error message when running jest unit tests:

```
TypeError: Cookies.set is not a function
```

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "jest-preset-angular": "11.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  }
```

Any idea where the change come from? Any known issues when unit testing jest in case of external dependencies with angular13?

I don't want to mock the methods of the external dependency **js-cookie**.

Example of the angular component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor() {
    Cookies.set('test', '123');
  }

}
```

Unit Test:

```
import {MyComponent} from './my-component.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const component: MyComponent = new MyComponent();

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is `js-cookie` a development-only dependency? This is going to crash as soon as you deploy it

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Here's what I've figured out.

1. You haven't properly installed `js-cookie`. Please run:

```sh
npm i js-cookie --save # Save keeps the dependency for the browser
```

and this one to get the TypeScript types:

```sh
npm i @types/js-cookie --save-dev  # Save dev saves the dependency to be used during build-time. (running tests or tooling)
```

2. Then; quoting from the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie)

> import Cookies from '/path/to/js.cookie.mjs'

You're importing it the wrong way: `import * as Cookies` you just want the default export from the library; not everything else.

3. Step 2 may cause your Angular 13 to not compile due to "synthetic default exports"-something else.

To address this add the following option in your `tsconfig.json` under the "compilerOptions" field:

```json
...
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
...
```

The problem was likely to be that the TypeScript compiler upgrade is noticing something that wasn't noticing before